# Why do I need if node after while queue to invert binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I was trying to [invert](https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/) a binary tree (i.e. swap all left & right children)

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node({self.value}, {self.left}, {self.right})"

from collections import deque

def invert(root):
    q=deque([root])
    while q:
        n=q.popleft() #n as in node
        if n: #why do I need this
            n.left,n.right=n.right,n.left
            q.append(n.left)
            q.append(n.right)
    return root

root = Node(1, Node(2), Node(3))
invert(root)
```

I realized if I remove `if n`, I get `NoneType` error. I was thinking if `while q` is true, then `if n` will always be true so `if n` is redundant code.

Comment: Show a [mcve] with the error. We can't debug code we can't see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is needed.

First of all it is needed when the tree is empty, because then that `q=deque([root])` will have put a `None` value on the queue, which should be ignored in the loop.

But also when the tree is not empty it is needed:

When a node `n` does not have both left and right children, then one (or both) of the `q.append` calls will append a `None` value on the queue. And so in one of the next iterations of the loop this `None` value will be popped from the queue. But in that case nothing should happen.

So yes, the `if` is needed.

You can rearrange the code, but somewhere you'll have to detect `None` values. For instance, take this variant:

(NB: the comment *"n as in node"* indicates you should just name it `node` instead of `n`)

```
if not root:
    return
queue = deque([root])
while queue:
    node = queue.popleft()
    node.left, node.right = node.right, node.left
    if node.left:
        queue.append(node.left)
    if node.right:
        queue.append(node.right)
return root
```

This version avoids that the queue would ever receive a `None` value, but it still means you need an `if` -- in this case three of them!